# How to change password for current user (not reset)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to run a query to let the user to change password manually. Is it possible ? if yes how ? I know the password field in the user table can't be modified. Is there a way to do it without using reset method of the parse.com

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereEqualTo("username", user.getUsername());
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,
                            ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            // The query was successful.

                            for (ParseUser ob : objects) {
                                ob.put("password", newpass1);
                               //user.setPassword(newpass1);

                            }

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Password Changed !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            progress.dismiss();
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // Something went wrong.
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to set the current user's password? If so simply use the following code:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currentUser.setPassword("new_password");
currentUser.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the password for the current user only:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currentUser.setPassword("newpassword");
currentUser.saveInBackground();
```

You never query for the ParseUser object of the current user, but rather use `ParseUser.getCurrentUser();`